# REACT JSX - Chained conditons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx, create-react-app

The following code works for me and gives me the expected results but I have doubts if I am doing it right.

```
{
  Conditon1?<ChildComponent />:Condition2?<p>Hi</p>:<p>Bye</p>
}
```

My concern is the chained conditional statement - is this valid?

Comment: It's a valid option, but can get a little difficult to read.  There's a lot of good documentation about [conditional rendering in the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html).  Give it a look-- they go over a few options, plus the pros and cons, and basically tell you to use what is best suited for your use case.

Comment: You can use parentheses to group the inner conditional statement or extract the conditionals outside the return statement so you can use the basic if-else pattern and save the markup in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the code statement you wrote is perfectly fine and would work, but I prefer to use better indentation while writing nested conditions so that the other person who reads the code get better understanding. Moreover when I have more chained conditions, I prefer using if/else rather than ternary operators.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's perfectly fine and should work!